# Find files and directories over a certain size

Tags: grep, disk-usage

I am currently using `du -sch /var/log/ | grep total | grep G` to find /var/log/ directories consuming over 1 GB space. It works perfectly.

I'm now looking to adjust this to do the same thing, but only show a result if the directory is over 5 GB.

How can this be done?

Comment: Note that your pipeline would be confused by a directory containing the string `total` in its name.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check directories you can omit the `-c`. And if you want to check the size you'd better omit the `-h` and use `-b` to get the size in bytes.

The `awk` command can be used to display only lines where the first column is larger than a specific size:

Try:

```
du -bs /var/log | awk '$1 >= 1*(1024*1024*1024)'
```

And/or:

```
du -bs /var/* | awk '$1 >= 1*(1024*1024*1024)'
```

If you want to find files of a certain size you can use the `find` utility like:

```
find /var/log -type f -size +1G
```

Comment: Note that `-b` (a GNU extension like `-h`) reports the apparent size as opposed to the disk usage. Use `du -sB1` to get the disk usage in number of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I see you can use `du` command with another option.

*du -h -d 1 -t 5G*

```
   -h, --human-readable
          print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)

   -d, --max-depth=N
          print the total for a directory (or file, with --all) only if it is N or fewer levels below the command line argument;  --max-depth=0 is the same as --summarize

   -t, --threshold=SIZE
          exclude entries smaller than SIZE if positive, or entries greater than SIZE if negative
```